# How to install Python modules within a virtualenv programatically?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

Before I get downvotes, this is not a duplicate. I have exhausted both google and SO. In SO, there are questions regarding how Python modules can be installed. But my question is creating a `venv` and installing modules to this created `venv` programatically. I have tried a few things;

My sample code

```
def create_venv_install_requirements(venv_folder, filename):
    print(f'Creating a new virtual environment')
    virtualenv.create_environment(venv_folder)
    activate_file = os.path.join(venv_folder, 'Scripts', 'activate_this.py')

    print('Installing requirements')
    with open(filename) as f:
        requirements = f.readlines()

    for item in requirements:
        exec(open(activate_file).read(), globals())
        subprocess.call(f'pip install {item}')
        # pip.main('install', item) this does not work as well
```

The issue I am facing is I can successfully create a `venv` but the modules cannot be installed within the created `venv`, instead they are being installed system wide. How can install packages within the activated `venv`?

Comment: What is `subprocess.call(f'pip install {item}')` meant to do?

Comment: have you activated `source venv/bin/activate` the venv before running the pip ?

Comment: @PeterWood that's a python f-string (a new formatting syntax available in 3.6 and later).

Comment: @taoufikA I have activated it using this line `exec(open(activate_file).read(), globals())`

Comment: My bad sorry, the problem is when you're calling subprocess the system creates a new process

Comment: Why don't you use a bash script ?

Comment: @taoufikA. I can't Bash. In case you can't see from my code, I am using a Windows system (`activate_file = os.path.join(venv_folder, 'Scripts', 'activate_this.py')`.

Comment: MMm sorry again, powershell or a .bat file ?

Comment: something like `START source env\Scripts\activate
START venv\Scripts\pip install -r requirements.txt` 
save it as .bat file and execute it, I ain't sure if it's the right syntax but it's gotta be something like that

Comment: I always wanted to know how to do this. I hope someone will find the answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your script is calling the wrong `pip` despite the fact that you're activating it.  You can *explicitly* call `pip` in the virtual environment (even without activating it like) this:

```
subprocess.call('{venv_folder}/bin/pip install {item}')
```

But don't actually do that, because if you have a list of requirements in a file you should just call:

```
subprocess.call('{venv_folder}/bin/pip install -r {filename}')
```

...and of course, in this case you don't need to open the requirements file and iterate over it yourself.

Note: For Windows systems, replace `bin` with `Scripts`

Comment: Actually I am activating it using `exec(open(activate_file).read(), globals())`. But thanks, I will try your method and report back

Comment: Sorry, I missed that line.  But try this anyway, because it sounds like python is looking for `pip` in the wrong place.